# Using Gmail API to update website when receiving an email

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

new to programming on the web so bear with me.

I've figured out that OAuth2.0 (the authorization protocol used by Gmail) is used for applications where Site A is given permission to information in Site B (in this case Gmail) by User X.

I am trying to create a website that updates when I receive an email from a specific sender. So, I am not using any of my website users' email information. I'm only using my own. I cannot seem to figure out (or even understand at a high level) how to permanently give my website access to my gmail account without doing some kind of user authentication on myself. What is the high-level process for giving my website this permanent authentication?

Let me know if I can make this clearer. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've never done what you are trying to do, but you may find some useful answers here :)

[Getting e-mail ID of sender while fetching mails from Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045894/getting-e-mail-id-of-sender-while-fetching-mails-from-gmail)

I hope this helps if not I'm sorry. :)

UPDATE:

After reading that link a little bit more there are parts of it where they are getting the sender. You can always write a code to compare the sender by implementing what you need from that link. :)